# Blazor binding is not working when calling a method from @ref component reference

Tags: c#, razor, binding, blazor

I have a simple Blazor component which is textbox that has been bound to a property:

```
<input @bind="TheValue" />

@code {
    public string TheValue { get; set; } = "abc";

    public void FillTextBox(string s)
    {
        TheValue = s;
        Console.WriteLine("TheValue is = " + TheValue);
    }
}
```

And in my main page where I used the component I have the following code:

```
<MyTextbox @ref="myTextbox" /></MyTextbox>

<button @onclick="@(()=>myTextbox.FillTextBox("123"))">Fill</button>

@code {
     MyTextbox myTextbox;
}
```

When the component is rendered it has the default value of "abc" and if I call the `FillTextBox` inside the component it also work fine but when I click the button although the `FillTextBox` will be executed (and displays the value in the console) it does not change the input element's value.
So to summarize the `@bind` does not work when I call the method that changes the binding variable .

**Update:** I'm seeking for data-binding or passing value to child components, I am looking for calling a previously-created  child component method without having to be concerned about whether the component will render itself correctly.

Comment: isn't it '<input @bind-value="@TheValue" />' ?

Comment: @RyanVettese I have tried this, still not working.

Comment: This is pretty serious issue I think. It just should work.

Answer (score 1):

I think when your component is used like this the component does not rerender. Maybe adding a method with StateHasChanged and allso calling this method does the job?

Comment: It worked but what is the point of two-way binding if have to explicitly notify if a bound value has been changed ?

Comment: The TwoWay binding works _inside_ MyTextbox. Your problem is in the communication between parent/child.

Comment: @nAviD - you may need to put @bind-value="newvalue" next to the component that consumes eg = <Textbox @ref="myTextbox" @bind-value="newvalue"></Textbox>